# What is a good definition of a "landing page"?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I would like to hear a good definition of a landing page and how to use one.
I simply can't really get the content of it.

- Where on the site do you place it? Index, popup, page, etc?
- What characterized a landing page?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely an [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_page) question.

> landing page, is a single web page that appears in response to
>   clicking on a search engine optimized search result or an online
>   advertisement.

Comment: So a landing page is more of an external page to your site? And then I assume that we can we can describe a landing page as a tool to advertise?

Comment: exactly - it's like one more "home page" - entry point of your site